# Displaying a java enum value with innerHTML using javascript

Tags: javascript, java, html, json

After using fetch to signal a java method via:

```
let res = await fetch(api call);
let data = await res.json();
```

I get data object returned to my javascript as follows:

```
description: "test case"
status: {status: "PENDING"}
```

The function responsible for displaying the data is like this:

```
let container = document.getElementById('id');
function populate(data){
for (obj of data) {
    let post = document.createElement('div');
    post.innerHTML = `<p>Description:  ${obj.description} and Status: ${obj.status.status}</p><br>`;
    container.append(post);
}
```

}

This results in the output:

test case and null

or

test case and [Object:object]

Status is an enum. How do I get the value of the enum to display with innerHTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your response looks like this:

```js
{
    description: "test case",
    status: {status: "PENDING"},
}
```

Then you need to use `${object.status.status}` instead of just `${object.status}`. That's why you get `[Object:object]`, since `object.status` is actually an object.